# How to control these components?

Tags: javascript, vuetify.js

I have 5 [`v-swtich`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selection-controls) components, called A, B, C, D and E.

Here is what I want to achieve:

- If I switch on **A**, then **D** and **E** must automatically switch on, and the user must not be able to switch D and E off unless if he switches off A.
- If **A** is not switched on, the the user can switch on **D** or **E**.
- If the user switches on any combinations where D and E appear (for example: (C, **D**, **E**), (C, **D**, **E**, B), (B, **D**, **E**) ) then A must be automatically switched on, and the user must not switch off D and E until he switches off A.

[image]

Here is some code to start with:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <p>{{ people }}</p>
      <v-switch v-model="people" label="A" value="A"></v-switch>
      <v-switch v-model="people" label="B" value="B"></v-switch>
      <v-switch v-model="people" label="C" value="C"></v-switch>
      <v-switch v-model="people" label="D" value="D"></v-switch>
      <v-switch v-model="people" label="E" value="E"></v-switch>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

The JS code:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      people: []
    }
  }
})
```

If I set the `value` prop to A, D and E components, whenever I toggle one of them on or off, the 2 others follow (and that is not what I want to do).

I really appreciate any help regarding this.

Comment: I don’t know the answer to your question, but one UX thing I would suggest is disabling the inputs that are not allowed to be toggled. Like if A is on, then force D and E on and disable D and E so that they cannot be toggled.

Comment: I would control this via state. Just render whenever there is toggle and before you set the state have a validator do the check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you wanted? [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mzPzyG) (or perhaps cleaner: [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bmpQpB))

```
<v-switch v-for="(person, i) in people" 
  :key="person.label"
  v-model="people[i].value"
  :label="people[i].label"
  :disabled="people[i].disabled"
></v-switch>

people: [
  { value: false, label: "A", disabled: false },
//...

created() {
// here we watch for D and E changes, and set A to true if both D and E are ON
this.$watch(
  vm => vm.people[3].value && vm.people[4].value, (newVal, oldVal) => {
    if(newVal) {
      this.people[0].value = true;
    }         
  });
},
watch: {
  "people.0.value"(newVal) {
    if (newVal) { // if A is turned ON
      // turn D and E on, and disable them
      this.people[3].value = true;
      this.people[4].value = true;
      this.people[3].disabled = true;
      this.people[4].disabled = true;
    } else { // if A is turned OFF
      // enable D and E
      this.people[3].disabled = false;
      this.people[4].disabled = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Not sure what else to add. Basically watch for changes and react on them.

Answer (score 0):

Using [computed getters/setters](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter) provides a method of backing view properties with logic. Rather than directly linking to `data`, Vue will call the computed methods with whatever logic has been supplied.

The second part of the problem is disabling buttons. This can be accomplished with the [`v-switch` `disabled`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selection-controls#api) property:

```
<v-switch
  :disabled="computedPropertyToDisable"
  v-model="computedPropertyForValue"
  ...
</v-switch>
```